# MegaRAID not accepting two out of four new identical drives

Tags: sas, megaraid, megacli

I've added four new drives (same model, HUH721010AL4200) to a server using a  (supermicro) server with a LSI MegaRAID 3108 controller. I want to make a new RAID10 array with them, but I'm having trouble getting them recognized.

Two of them are detected as `Unconfigured(good)`, the other two are `Unconfigured(bad)`. They do show up with the right model number, correct link speed etc but showing a size of 0 bytes.

```
Raw Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 0 KB [0x0 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
```

Even though you wouldn't expect there to be existing headers on the 'bad' drives, I've tried to clear any foreign configuration and run `MegaCli64 -PDMakeGood` on them but this failed, even with a -Force.

I've swapped the drives around to see if it was the bays or the drives and it appears to be the drives.

I can't find any clue as to what's going on in the log files. I'm only seeing this

```
10/15/18 11:47:41: C0:EVT#31954-10/15/18 11:47:41:  91=Inserted: PD 59(e0x4a/s15)
10/15/18 11:47:41: C0:EVT#31955-10/15/18 11:47:41: 247=Inserted: PD 59(e0x4a/s15) Info: enclPd=4a, scsiType=0, portMap=02, sasAddr=5000cca26a615651,0000000000000000
10/15/18 11:47:41: C0:EVT#31956-10/15/18 11:47:41: 131=Unable to access device PD 59(e0x4a/s15)
```

and, in dmesg:

```
[Mon Oct 15 14:07:40 2018] megaraid_sas 0000:02:00.0: 31956 (592919261s/0x0002/FATAL) - Unable to access device PD 59(e0x4a/s15)
[Mon Oct 15 14:07:41 2018] megaraid_sas 0000:02:00.0: 31960 (592919261s/0x0002/FATAL) - Unable to access device PD 5a(e0x4a/s14)
```

A reboot doesn't change things either. The drives are also showing up as 0MB size in the RAID BIOS.